# Drawing multiple shapes onto a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, pong

I apologise if this has any element of ambiguity, but I am kind of overwhelmed by the Java Swing/AWT libraries (I hate GUI programming!).

Basically I have set up a very basic JFrame with a JPanel as such:

```
public void drawGUI() {
    //Instantiate the JFrame.
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Ping Pong alpha1");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Instantiate & setup the JPanels.
    btnPan = new JPanel();
    canPan = new JPanel();
    canPan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(canPan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    statPan = new JPanel();
    statPan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statPan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //Add JPanels to mainFrame.
    mainFrame.add(btnPan, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    mainFrame.add(canPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.add(statPan, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    //Instantiate & setup JMenuBar.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainFrame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    //Instantiate JMenu's & JMenuItem's.
    gameMenu = new JMenu("Game");
    helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
    newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
    exit = new JMenuItem("Exit Game");
    about = new JMenuItem("About");

    //Add JMenuItems to their JMenu's.
    gameMenu.add(newGame);
    gameMenu.add(exit);
    helpMenu.add(about);
    menuBar.add(gameMenu);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    //Add items to JPanels.
    canvas = new PongCanvas();
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

    //Set window parameters and pack.
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

My question is this; is there a way of drawing components dynamically onto the *canPan* object? i.e. a circle and some rectangles? The position of these components will of course change with user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, override it's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and draw on a copy of the passed `Graphics` object (which you will subsequently dispose of).

For more information, see [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks, my lecturer had mentioned something about this before. What exactly does the Graphics object do? Pleas excuse my ignorance; I never really do this kind of work.

Comment: @VisionIncision, See [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).